# laravel: cannot type in console after starting a server

Tags: php, laravel, types, console, laravel-artisan

I have recently started studying Laravel and I noticed that after I start a server (php artisan serve) I can no longer type anything in the console and I have to close and reopen it to be able to type again.

Here is what is written in the console:

C:\Xampp\Xampp\htdocs\telerikFifthHomework>php artisan controller:make UserContr
oller
Controller created successfully!

C:\Xampp\Xampp\htdocs\telerikFifthHomework>php artisan serve
Laravel development server started on http:// localhost:8000
[Tue Dec 09 22:51:15 2014] ::1:5013 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:51:23 2014] ::1:5042 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:51:39 2014] ::1:5096 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:51:54 2014] ::1:5140 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:35 2014] ::1:5260 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:37 2014] ::1:5266 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:37 2014] ::1:5272 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:37 2014] ::1:5274 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:38 2014] ::1:5280 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:38 2014] ::1:5283 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:52:57 2014] ::1:5339 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:53:01 2014] ::1:5350 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:54:07 2014] ::1:5574 [200]: /favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 09 22:54:12 2014] ::1:5590 [200]: /favicon.ico

Any suggestions?

Comment: open another console window. or see [this superuser answer](http://superuser.com/a/591084/144297)

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+C will exit serve and return to prompt.  Execute what you need and then serve again.

Answer (score 0):

if you just started with laravel, i'd suggest to setup homestead first. This is a better way to work since you dont have to worry about server maintanance anymore and you can just focus on making a website.
This will also resolve this problem, since you use a vm to handle the server.
For more info about homestead, here are some links:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead

https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two